# Authorize Personalizado

Tags: asp.net-web-api

estoy haciendo un modulo de roles y permisos en .net mvc con webapi.

La cuestion es que mi authorize viene de System.Web.Http

Y no se como personalizarlo para poder usar permisos de mi base de datos para acceder a controlador y a metodos de los controladores

Una cosa asi: Authorize[Permisos=1] o Authorize[Permisos="EditarRol"] ponele

Desde ya gracias

Comment: No acabo de entender exactamente lo que quieres. ¿El problema lo tienes en los controladores MVC o en Web API? ¿Lo que quieres es crear un atributo de autorización personalizado para controladores MVC?

Comment: Mi problema es que no se como hacer un authorize personalizado para mis controladores, el authorize que tengo en los controladores es de System.web.http ya que uso webapi para acceder a ellos. Para que te des una idea es algo parecido a esto pero para web api ya que AuthorizeCore no existe en AuthorizeAttribute de System.web.http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es autorizar el acceso a un controlador WebAPI en función de los roles del usuario actual y utilizas la autenticación de ASP.NET puedes utilizar el atributo `AuthorizationAttribute` de WebAPI:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "RolEdicion")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
  ...
}
```

Entiendo que no es tu caso. Pero si utilizas la autenticación de ASP.NET y quieres hacer un proceso de autorización personalizado pero basado en el usuario actual de ASP.NET y sus roles, puedes crear un atributo heredando de `AuthorizeAttribute`, de esta forma ya tendrás implementada en la clase base la posibilidad de restringir el acceso en función del usuario o sus roles.

Si por el contrario, como me ha parecido entender, quieres hacer un sistema de autorización completamente personalizado, puedes crearte un atributo que herede de la clase `AuthorizationFilterAttribute` y sobrescribir el método `OnAuthorization` para implementar ahí tus restricciones de acceso.

Algo así:

```
public class MyAuthorizationAttribute: AuthorizationFilterAttribute
{

    private readonly string _permisos;

    public MyAuthorizationAttribute(string Permisos)
    {
        _permisos = Permisos;
    }

    public override void OnAuthorization(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!ComprobarPermisos())
        {
            actionContext.Response=new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
        }
        base.OnAuthorization(actionContext);
    }

    private bool ComprobarPermisos()
    {
        bool tienePermiso;
        // Lógica de comprobación de autorización
        // ....
        return tienePermiso;
    }
}
```

Este código crea una atributo de autorización `MyAuthorizationAttribute` que acepta un argumento `Permisos` de tipo `string`.
En el método `OnAuthorization` se llama al método privado `ComprobarPermisos` que es el encargado de decidir si el usuario tiene permiso para acceder al controlador o no. En caso de no tener permiso se devuelve un código de estado 401 (no autorizado).

En el controlador bastaría con decorar la clase con el atributo indicándole en `Permisos` el valor a utilizar:

```
[MyAuthorization(Permisos:"RolEdicion")]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
  ...
}
```